# Changing the metric of an interface permanently

Tags: networking, routing

This is my routing table when I connect my Android phone via USB to my Raspberry and enable USB-tethering.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 usb0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 usb0
```

I want `wlan0` to be the preferred interface.
So how can I change the metric of one the interfaces permanently?

Also how does Linux decide which metric value it will use for an interface?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344974/how-can-i-make-changes-to-the-network-routing-metric-permanently/345057

Comment: Sorry, but these answers don't work. 
1) I don't have nmcli. 2) /etc/dhcpd.conf does not exist. 3) /etc/NetworkManager/ does also not exist.

Comment: Well what Linux distribution are you running? It is hard to answer without knowing.

Comment: Raspbian on Raspberry PI 3

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498676/173437

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the solutions is to configure settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` adding default route with a predefined metric:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static 
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
    post-up /sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 metric 10
    post-down /sbin/ip route del default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 metric 10
    wpa-ssid <your_SSID>
    wpa-psk <your_PSK>
```

Maybe, you need to add another Wi-Fi options specific to your settings.

---

Another solution is to change the metric in the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.
According to the [dhcpcd manual](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html) metric can be assigned to the interface:

> ```
> metric
>          Metrics are used to prefer an interface over another one, lowest
>          wins.  dhcpcd will supply a default metric of 200 +
>          if_nametoindex(3).  An extra 100 will be added for wireless
>          interfaces.
> ```

Add these lines to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
metric 200

interface usb0
metric 300
```

And restart dhcpcd and networking services.

Comment: my /etc/networking/interfaces looks like this, so can I still add them?:
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)                                              
                                                                                                
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd                                  
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

Comment: Could you please show the content of the directory **/etc/network/interfaces.d**? If there are no interfaces, you can add that config.

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces.d is empty.

Comment: I don't want to have a fixed default gateway and I still want to use dhcp. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf ?

Comment: /etc/dhcpcd.conf: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/g3KrY8zU)

Comment: See another solution in the answer.

Comment: sorry, **/etc/dhcpd.conf** does not exist. I had to create **/etc/dhcpd.conf** and it doesn't work after rebooting, the metric is not changed :(

Comment: opps, not /etc/dhcpd.conf, but /etc/dhcpcd.conf

Comment: I also tried adding to **/etc/dhcpcd.conf** with the same results. (metric is not changed after rebooting)

Comment: Remove the ";". Then it works!