# dhcpcd: set priority for link-local connections

Tags: route, priority, dhcpcd, metric

I see that there is a [`metric` keyword](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html#metric) in the `dhcpcd.conf` (as explained e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413036/47009), which allows me to set the routing priority for a given interface.

However, i would like to *only* set the metric for `link-local` connections on that interface (and use a different metric for other connection types on the same interface).

Is this possible? If so, how?

#### Background

I'm configuring networking (on my Raspberry Pi, but that's beside the point) with `dhcpcd`.

With simple setups (a single connection) this works fine, for `DHCP` and `link-local` connections on my `eth0` interface, and for `DHCP` connections on my `wlan0` interface.

Unfortunately, my regular use-case involves having a dual-connection setup, where users connect via a `link-local` connection between their laptop and the RPi (to control the headless device via VNC) and then connect the RPi via WiFi to some network for "internet access" (users are not tech savy, so they would be at a loss of setting up their laptop to act as a router providing uplink connectivity for the `link-local` connections).

Now the problem I'm facing is that if i have *both* a ethernet `link-local` connection and a WiFi `DHCP` connection, then both connections define a `default` route (which is not a problem per-se), and the `link-local` connection has a higher priority than my WiFi connection.
Since the `link-local` peer is not setup to do any routing, this effectively means that the device does not have a *working* `default` route, and therefore there is no "internet access".

```bash
$ ip route show

default dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.204.108 metric 202 
default via 192.168.64.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 303 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.204.108 metric 202 
192.168.64.0/21 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.69.188 metric 303
```

(lower `metric` values are preferred)

Now, the default for `dhcpcd` makes sense in many situations, as typically ethernet connections are faster and more reliable than WiFi connections.

So I would really like to keep the higher priority of `DHCP` ethernet connections over arbitrary WiFi connections, but have `link-local` ethernet connections have the lowest priority (highest `metric`).

##### further information

All tests are done with:

```bash
$ dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 8.1.2
Copyright (c) 2006-2019 Roy Marples
Compiled in features: INET ARP ARPing IPv4LL INET6 DHCPv6 AUTH
```

As has been observed in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761022/dhcpcd-set-priority-for-link-local-connections?noredirect=1#comment1451212_761022), a link-local connection shouldn't have a route at all (which is fine for me).

So to debug this issue further, I give my entire `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
option ntp_servers
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
allowinterfaces eth0
```

as you can see, `dhcpcd` only manages `eth0` (I lied above, when I said that `dhcpcd` was managing all network connections; in reality, the WiFi connections are managed by NetworkManger (which in turn has a line `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth0` in it's configuration).

To check whether NetworkManager is at fault, I've disabled it temporarily, and rebooted.

Plugin in the network cable, I see the following in my logs:

```
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus dhcpcd[451]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.204.108
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus dhcpcd[451]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus dhcpcd[451]: eth0: adding default route
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus avahi-daemon[532]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.204.108.
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus avahi-daemon[532]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov 09 17:02:14 mungus avahi-daemon[532]: Registering new address record for 169.254.204.108 on eth0.IPv4.
```

Comment: dhcpcd has a `-m <metric>` parameter. Furthermore, if the defaultroute via eth0 isn't working, you should simply not set it.

Comment: @stoney yes i know, this is what the `metric` keyword mentioned in the question is about. the question is, how can i apply the `metric` to only link-local interfaces?

Comment: @A.B good observation. i've now posted my `dhcpcd.conf` (and also a little bit more details about my *actual* network setup, which unfortunately also has to include NetworkManager for managing the WiFi interfaces). Given that `dhcpcd` is told to only manage `eth0` and NM is explicitely forbidden to do so, i thought I could drop this info as unnecessary, but now that things start to smell fishy, i've added them.

Comment: so how would i prevent `dhcpcd` from adding this buggy default route?

Comment: only now i've added the 'further information' section, so no wonder you didn't see it before.

Comment: I can imagine now the need of such default route (it depends on what are doing other systems in this LAN and what's their address). So you'd rather use  @stoney 's suggestion.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately i do not understand @stoney's suggestion: setting the `-m <metric>` flag will apply to all routes, not just the `link-local` one. **not setting** the route for only link-local connections sounds like a good idea, but...how?